# Application of martingale central limit theorem

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, central-limit-theorem

I just learned martingale central limit theorem and got a problem at hand and do not know how to form the correct martingale.

Suppose we draw balls successively from a box of $2n$ balls and $n$ balls are marked with -1 and the other half are marked by 1.

Now, label these successive draws $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_{2n}$, and for each $m\leq 2n$,write $S_{m,2n} = \sum_{i=1}^{m} X_i$. Try to prove that $\forall t\in(0,1)$,
$$\frac{S_{[2nt],2n}}{\sqrt{n}} \rightarrow ^D N(0,v_t^2).$$

I was thingking that maybe $S_{m,2n}$ would be some form of martingale but it seems not so and I do not know what to do next. Any idea on forming the martingale?

Comment: It may work to consider the martingale $$Y_k = \frac{S_1}{2n - 1} + \frac{S_2}{2n-2} + \cdots + \frac{S_{k-1}}{2n - k+1} + S_k$$

Comment: Thanks! @SameerKailasa, I have tried to use $S_k/(2n-k)$ which finally works!